# Is there a way to programmatically access the Apache Velocity cache?

Tags: apache, caching, velocity

My web application is using Velocity, and my resource loader has caching enabled.  Is it possible to manually access the values in the cache?  All I really need to do is remove a particular entry at a given time.

Comment: Do you want to reset the template cache?

Comment: That would work.  I'd prefer to only remove a given entry though.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should reset the template cache:

```
VelocityEngine velocity = new VelocityEngine();
velocity.getTemplate("tpl.vm").touch();
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as the VelocityEngine doesn't seems to know about my templates.  Is it possible for me to access the VelocityEngine being used from another servlet?

Comment: @safetyguy1656 Well of course you need to use velocityEngine used in your application, I just put constructor there so you can see what `velocity` is. How to access it depends on how your project is built, I can't answer it without seeing the code. Do you init velocity manually or it is created behind the scenes?

Comment: I figured out how to do this; I just made my servlet extend VelocityViewServlet, which gave me the access I needed.  Unfortunately though, it doesn't seem that touch() does what I want.  From looking at the code, it looks like it only sets the nextCheck time in the future, depending on the Velocity cache modification check interval set in the properties.  So that's really the opposite of what I need to do.  Hopefully this will get me going in the right direction though.